# H2O Frame is Empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, h2o

I'm trying to run some sample code that I found from the link below.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#automl-interface

I modified the code a bit.  My actual code is below.

```
import h2o
from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

h2o.init()

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\taxi.csv', header=0, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df.head(10)

df = df[:100000]

y = df.fare_amount

# create training and testing vars
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.2)

# Identify predictors and response
y = df['fare_amount']
del df['fare_amount']
x = df

# Run AutoML for 20 base models (limited to 1 hour max runtime by default)
train = h2o.H2OFrame(df)

aml = H2OAutoML(max_models=20, seed=1)
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

# View the AutoML Leaderboard
lb = aml.leaderboard
lb.head(rows=lb.nrows)
```

I set 'fare_amount' as my target variable.  When I run the code all I get is this message: 'This H2OFrame is empty.'  I may be missing something pretty basic, but I can't see what it is.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: do you see output from `df.head()`? it seems like the most likely problem here is that you're not reading in the csv correctly

Comment: *Where exactly* does the error pop up? What's the point of including a whole bunch of `.shape` and `.head` commands here without showing a single result of them?

Comment: Yes, I definitely see the results from df.head(10).  I kn=ind of feel like the error comes from here: train = h2o.H2OFrame(df).  I got that from the h2o documentation.  That should be fine, I think.

Comment: Well, the .shape and the .head are strictly for my benefit.  I will remove them eventually.  It's just to QA my work.  It seems like the problem stems from here: train = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
However, when I review that, it seems ok.  Maybe I am missing something on that line of code.  Not sure.

Comment: "It seems"? Please post the full error trace. And stuff in the code for your benefit are expected to be removed here, where code is supposed to be **minimal**, among other things (edited).

Comment: I shared everything I have.  If I click Tool > Analyze Stack Trace...this is what I see: This H2OFrame is empty.